# Checking type of error in LocalAuthentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

I know this may be a simple question but I can't find what I'm looking for on the internet. I'm using the LocalAuthentication framework from iOS 8 in my project and my code is here:

```
 if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {
            [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                    localizedReason:@"Let's just quickly check that you are the device owner."
                              reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                  dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                      if (error) {
                                          // Error occurred
                                      } else if (success) {
                                          // Device owner, success!
                                      } else {
                                          // Not device owner
                                      }
                                  });
                              }];
        }
```

But I want to know when the user tapped 'Enter password' which is `LAErrorUserFallback`. However I just want to know how to compare the `error` variable I have there with the `LAErrorUserFallback` to see the outcome error.

I have tried this:

```
if (error) {
    if (error == LAErrorUserFallback) {
       // User tapped 'Enter password'
    }
}
```

but obviously these are not the same type.

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/LAError), that's the error code.
So try something like `error.code == LAErrorUserFallback`.